# Printing value to Tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to insert my output value to a Tkinter label.

Here's my code:

```
def get_Host_name_IP():
    try:
        host_name = socket.gethostname()
        host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
        print("Hostname :  ", host_name)
        print("IP : ", host_ip)
    outputtext = Text(host_ip)
    except:
        print("Unable to get Hostname and IP")
```

I want the IP_adress to be displayed in a label like this:

```
Label (window, text="IP adress", bg="black", fg="Black", font="none 11 bold") .grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return `host_ip` from a function similar to yours

```
def get_IP():
    try:
        host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
        return host_ip
    except:
        print("Unable to get IP")
```

and use in this :

```
Label (window, text=get_IP(), bg="black", fg="Black", font="none 11 bold") .grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W)
```